# Consolidating multiple copies of a character at start of string into one in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm working on a parser for a mini language, and I have the need to differentiate between plain strings ("hello") and strings that are meant to be operators/commands, and start with a specific sigil character (e.g. "$add").

I also want to add a way for the user to escape the sigil, in which a double-sigil gets consolidated into one, and then is treated like a plain string.

As an example:
`"hello"` becomes `Str("hello")`
`"$add"` becomes `Operator(Op::Add)`
`"$$add"` becomes `Str("$add")`

What would be the best way to do this check and manipulation? I was looking for a method that counts how many times a character appears at the start of a string, to no avail.

Comment: You have several possible paths. The simplest and most immediate would be regular expressions. There's a very good crate in rust for that and those transformations are trivial. For the long term, depending on the complexity of your language, you'll probably need a parser approach.

Comment: *"I was looking for a method that counts how many times a character appears at the start of a string"* What was exactly the problem with doing that ? What prevented you from counting the number of `$` at the start of a string ?

Comment: Whats wrong with `if string is longer than 1 char and first char is equal to second char`?

Comment: @hyde Is there a good way to index by character? It seems that doing do isn't encouraged.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just use `starts_with`?

```
fn main() {
    let line_list= [ "hello", "$add", "$$add" ];
    let mut result;
    for line in line_list.iter() {
        if line.starts_with("$$") {
            result = line[1..].to_string();
        }
        else if line.starts_with("$") {
            result = format!("operator:{}", &line[1..]);
        }
        else {
            result = line.to_string();
        }
        println!("result = {}", result);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
result = hello
result = operator:add
result = $add
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments, your problem seems to be related to the access to the first chars.

The proper and efficient way is to [get a char iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Token {
    Str(String),
    Operator(String),
}
impl From<&str> for Token {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Self {
        let mut chars = s.chars();
        let first_char = chars.next();
        let second_char = chars.next();
        match (first_char, second_char) {
            (Some('$'), Some('$')) => {
                Token::Str(format!("${}", chars.as_str()))
            }
            (Some('$'), Some(c)) => {
                // your real handling here is probably different
                Token::Operator(format!("{}{}", c, chars.as_str()))
            }
            _ => {
                Token::Str(s.to_string())
            }
        }        
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Token::from("π"));
    println!("{:?}", Token::from("hello"));
    println!("{:?}", Token::from("$add"));
    println!("{:?}", Token::from("$$add"));
}
```

Result:

```
Str("π")
Str("hello")
Operator("add")
Str("$add")
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=41c6ec85921980ed5d4fd2989d1a2245)